Invalid login attempt error while Integrating NetSuite using RESTlet from Salesforce Apex
I'm struggling to connect NetSuite with Salesforce to create Customer Records in NetSuite using RESTlet scripts and OAuth 1 for authorization. While I can create records using POSTMAN, attempts from Apex callouts fail with a 403 Forbidden error and "Invalid login attempt" message. The NetSuite Login Audit Trail indicates "InvalidSignature."
I tried connecting NetSuite using REST web service and then with RESTlet scripts with Salesforce. But both the approaches work well from POSTMAN and throw 403 Forbidden, Invalid Login Attempt error in Apex when tried from Salesforce Apex callout. When checked in the Login Audit trail of NetSuite, the detail column shows InvalidSignature error.
It should be succesfully authenticated from Salesforce apex callout the way it does from POSTMAN.
I've double-checked parameters and used HMAC-SHA256 Signature. Any insights on resolving this would be appreciated. Also, if you've connected NetSuite with Salesforce successfully before, I'd love to hear your approach.

here's the code for my ref.
Here's the code snippet for callout:
public class AuthNetSuite {  private static final String NETSUITE_RESTLET_URL = 'https://(ACCOUNT_ID).http://restlets.api.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=(SCRIPT_ID)&deploy=(DEPLOY_ID)';

  private static final String CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

  private static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

  private static final String ACCESS_TOKEN = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

  private static final String TOKEN_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

  private static final String REALM = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';  public static HttpResponse calloutToNet(String endPoint, String bodyString, String methodName) {

    HttpRequest httpRequestObject = new HttpRequest();

    httpRequestObject.setEndpoint(endPoint);

    httpRequestObject.setMethod(methodName);

    httpRequestObject.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    //httpRequestObject.setTimeout(120000); // Setting timeout to 2 minutes    if(bodyString != null) {

      httpRequestObject.setBody(bodyString);

    }    String authHeader = OAuth1.getAuthorizationHeader('POST', NETSUITE_RESTLET_URL, ACCESS_TOKEN, TOKEN_SECRET, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, REALM);

    system.debug('authHeader '+authHeader);    httpRequestObject.setHeader('Authorization',authHeader);    Http http = new Http();

    HttpResponse httpResponse = http.send(httpRequestObject);

    System.debug('Status Code: '+httpResponse.getStatusCode()+', Status: '+httpResponse.getStatus()+', Body: '+httpResponse.getBody());    return httpResponse;

  }
}

Here's the code snippet: Signature construction
 public static String getAuthorizationHeader(String method, String url, String oauthToken, String oauthTokenSecret, String consumerKey, String consumerSecret, String realm) {

    String oauthNonce = generateNonce();

    String oauthTimestamp = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);

    system.debug('oauthTimestamp '+oauthTimestamp);

    // Construct signature base string

    String signatureBaseString = constructSignatureBaseString(method, url, oauthNonce, oauthTimestamp, oauthToken, consumerKey, realm);

    // Construct signing key

    String signingKey = consumerSecret + '&' + oauthTokenSecret;

    // Generate signature

    Blob hmac = Crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA256', Blob.valueOf(signatureBaseString), Blob.valueOf(signingKey));

    String signature = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(hmac);

    // Construct authorization header

    String authHeader = 'OAuth ';

    authHeader += 'oauth_consumer_key="' + consumerKey + '",';

    authHeader += 'oauth_nonce="' + oauthNonce + '",';

    authHeader += 'realm="' + realm + '",';

    authHeader += 'oauth_signature="' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(signature, 'UTF-8') + '",';

    authHeader += 'oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256",';

    authHeader += 'oauth_timestamp="' + oauthTimestamp + '",';

    authHeader += 'oauth_token="' + oauthToken + '",';

    authHeader += 'oauth_version="1.0"';

    return authHeader;

  }  private static String generateNonce() {

    return EncodingUtil.convertToHex(Crypto.generateAesKey(128)).substring(0, 32);

  }  private static String constructSignatureBaseString(String method, String url, String oauthNonce, String oauthTimestamp, String oauthToken, String consumerKey, String realm) {

    method = method.toUpperCase();

    url = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(url, 'UTF-8');    String signatureParams = 'oauth_consumer_key=' + consumerKey +

      '&oauth_nonce=' + oauthNonce +

      '&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA256' +

      '&oauth_timestamp=' + oauthTimestamp +

      '&oauth_token=' + oauthToken +

      '&oauth_version=1.0';    if (!String.isBlank(realm)) {

      signatureParams += '&realm=' + realm;

    }    return method + '&' + url + '&' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(signatureParams, 'UTF-8');
  }


Please add your code.

I assume you are setting up your signature in your code, with something like this for your normal requests and then using HMAC-SHA256. With postman, for  both situations below, it does it for you so it can be  confusing why postman works, but not your code:
        data = $"oauth_consumer_key={config["consumerKey"]}" +
            $"&oauth_nonce={oauthNonce}" +
            $"&oauth_signature_method={config["signMethod"]}" +
            $"&oauth_timestamp={timestamp}&oauth_token={config["tokenId"]}" +
            $"&oauth_version={config["oauthVersion"]}";

When you hit a parameter endpoint for the restlet... something like: https://YOURACCOUNTID.restlets.api.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?scriptId=SCRIPTID&deployId=DEPLOYID you need to include those parameters in the signature generation. They need to show up in alphabetical order too. so the above would change to:
        data = $"deploy={DEPLOYID}" +
            $"&oauth_consumer_key={config["consumerKey"]}" +
            $"&oauth_nonce={oauthNonce}" +
            $"&oauth_signature_method={config["signMethod"]}" +
            $"&oauth_timestamp={timestamp}&oauth_token={config["tokenId"]}" +
            $"&oauth_version={config["oauthVersion"]}&script={SCRIPTID}";

Note you only pass the base script url without parameters when building the signature vaules and key:
    var signatureValue = $"POST&Uri.EscapeDataString(https://YOURACCOUNTID.restlets.api.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl)}&{Uri.EscapeDataString(data)}";
    var signatureKey = $"{Uri.EscapeDataString(config["consumerSecret"])}&{Uri.EscapeDataString(config["tokenSecret"])}";

But you need to send the entire uri (with query parameters) in the post uri for your HttpRequestMessage.
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, https://YOURACCOUNTID.restlets.api.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?scriptId={SCRIPTID}&deployId={DEPLOYID})
            {
                Content = payload
            };
            foreach (var header in headers)
            {
                request.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
            }
            return await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

Assuming "headers" is a Dictionary<string,string> that you get from creating your headers
